# PhoneGap Build Android Not Displaying Splashscreen

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, splash-screen, phonegap

Here is my code in my config.xml that's relative to splash screens:

```
    <splash src="splash.png" />
    <icon src="icon.png"/>
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
    <platform name="android">
        <preference name="SplashScreen" value="res/screens/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />  
        <splash src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png"/>  
        <icon density="ldpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="res/screens/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <preference name="SplashScreen" value="res/screens/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" />  
        <splash src="res/screens/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png"/>  
        <icon height="57" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="50" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="29" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <splash height="1136" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="768" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1024" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
    </platform>
```

On iOS the splash screen is displayed perfectly but on android nothing is displayed at all. Does anybody have any suggestions on how to fix this error? I've tried adding the cordova splashscreen plugin but that seems to crash the android app on open. Am I missing another essential piece of code?

Comment: Hello @zmalter99 
Try removing the next tags inside the android tag:
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="res/screens/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />  
<splash src="res/screens/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png"/>

Answer (score 0):

I created one sample for you and I checked in device and splash screen is appeared.

Add the plugin

> cordova-plugin-splashscreen

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Splashscreen Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/PushNotification.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.splashscreen.show();
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

config.xml

```
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <platform name="android">            
            <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
            <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
            <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
            <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
            <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
            <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        </platform>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~3.2.1" />
```

I created one folder named "resources" and add the splash screen images and give its path in config.xml file.

And it's working.