# Phonegap Build: splash not showing any more in Android apk

Tags: cordova, phonegap, splash-screen

I've been developing an app for some weeks and never had problems with showing a splashscreen using Phonegap Build (Android).
Since some days the splashscreen isn't displayed any more. No paths have been changed, splash.png is there as it was before.
I tried a backup of an earlier version of my app, which was working for sure: same issue.
Has anyone the same problem?

This is my configuration file (not modifed for quite a long time):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<widget id="de.xxx.myhue" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<name>MyHue</name>
<description>MyHue</description>
<author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">PhoneGap Team</author>
<content src="index.html" />

<config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest" mode="merge">
<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></application>
</config-file>

<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
<preference name="orientation" value="default" />
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
<preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" /> 
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />

<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />

<preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="5.0.1" />
<icon src="icon.png" />
<splash height="1920" platform="android" src="splash.png" width="1080" />
<access origin="*" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
<allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<engine name="android" spec="~4.1.1" />
```

Thanks Uli

Comment: Please check the splash screen plugin.
Is there any update or not.

Comment: I checked that before - version 5.0.1 (which I use) is the latest.

Comment: Please [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45823973/phonegap-build-android-not-displaying-splashscreen/45832962#45832962) this answer.
It is working example.

Comment: Thanks, I tried you sample - same issue using Phonegap Build.

Comment: is there any error or show nothing in splash screen ?

Comment: No error, just showing a blank screen.

Comment: Okay.
Did you put images "resources/android/splash" here ?

Comment: Yes. I double checked that.

Comment: the "resources" folder put in the main project structure.
And splash image put in the "SplashExample/resources/android/splash". Its like this.

Comment: Exactly like this!

Comment: Try to update your Android.
Using this command.
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android@6.2.0

Comment: As I said before: I use Phonegap Build: https://build.phonegap.com

Comment: Yes, but your android version is 4.1.1 which is mentioned in your config.xml in the last. So you need to update your android version and try my example.

Comment: Ok, I see. Changed that and also tried 6.1.2 (which seems to be the current version of Phonegap Build) - same issue. Thanks for your help anyway - I worked around that by creating a native Android app with a webview loading my website. That works fine.