# Splashscreen is not working on phonegap build app or google chrome

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap

This question has been asked but I've tried nearly all of the possible solutions and nothing has worked so far. I'm a newbie to Phonegap and I'm having difficulty displaying my splash screen when I test it on both my laptop using google chrome and the phone gap app, which I have installed to test my application.

My config.xml file code looks like this:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true"/>
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="~3.2.1" />

<platform name="android">
<icon density="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/android/land-ldpi.png" platform="android" qualifier="land-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="www/res/screen/android/land-mdpi.png" platform="android" qualifier="land-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="www/res/screen/android/land-hdpi.png" platform="android" qualifier="land-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="www/res/screen/android/land-xhdpi.png" platform="android" qualifier="land-xhdpi"/>
        <splash src="www/res/screen/android/land-xxdpi.png" platform="android" qualifier="land-xxhdpi"/>
        <splash src="www/res/screen/android/land-xxxdpi.png" platform="android" qualifier="land-xxxhdpi"/>
        <splash src="www/res/screen/android/ldpi.png" platform="android" qualifier="port-ldpi" />
        <splash src="www/res/screen/android/mdpi.png" platform="android" qualifier="port-mdpi" />
        <splash src="www/res/screen/android/hdpi.png" platform="android" qualifier="port-hdpi" />
        <splash src="www/res/screen/android/xhdpi.png" platform="android" qualifier="port-xhdpi" />
        <splash src="www/res/screen/android/xxhdpi.png" platform="android" qualifier="port-xxhdpi" />
        <splash src="www/res/screen/android/xxxhdpi.png" platform="android" qualifier="port-xxxhdpi" />
        <splash src="splash.png" />
    </platform>
```

My config.xml file and the splash.png file is in my www folder.

If someone could please help me that would be great. I don't know where I am going wrong.

Thank you :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45823973/phonegap-build-android-not-displaying-splashscreen/45832962#45832962
Refer this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Below you will find an example config.xml, generated by Ionic:

```
...
<platform name="ios">
   <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
   <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
    ...
</platform>
<platform name="android">
    <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    ...
</platform>
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^3.2.2" />
...
```

The folder these files are located are {project_root}/resources/... **not within the www folder. The splashscreen is a cordova plugin, it will not show up in the browser.**